# Change a SF Symbol size inside a UIButton

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uibutton, sf-symbols

I am declaring a Button like this :

```
let menuButton = UIButton()
```

After that I am trying to change it's parameter and set his position on the view with the help of LBTATools (a pod) with this function:

```
fileprivate func setMenuButtonUI() {
        menuButton.setImage(UIImage(systemName: "line.horizontal.3.decrease.circle.fill"), for: .normal)
        view.addSubview(menuButton)
        menuButton.anchor(top: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, leading: view.leadingAnchor, bottom: nil, trailing: nil, padding: .init(top: 20, left: 60, bottom: 0, right: 0), size: .init(width: 40, height: 40))
        menuButton.setupShadow(opacity: 1, radius: 5, offset: .zero, color: .darkGray)
        menuButton.tintColor = .red
    }
```

Everything is working well, I get the right color, position and even size.
Only problem is it's size, I cannot change it with all the usual methods like `menuButton.imageView?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit` etc..

Probably it comes from the fact that it is a SF Symbol and not a normal image.

The help of someone would be really appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 168, accepted):

You can do it using `SymbolConfiguration` like in the sample code below:

```
let largeConfig = UIImage.SymbolConfiguration(pointSize: 140, weight: .bold, scale: .large)
       
let largeBoldDoc = UIImage(systemName: "doc.circle.fill", withConfiguration: largeConfig)

button.setImage(largeBoldDoc, for: .normal)
```

[image]

Comment: This is really nice when using SF symbol in UIButton. While it is tricky to use imageEdgeInsets to change the image size in UIButton.

Comment: It's not centered, as I can see.

Comment: Its not centered because the x is 100 and the y is 200

Answer (score 21):

The iOS 15 and Swift 5 solution would be:

```
var config = UIButton.Configuration.plain() // Change style with e.g. `.filled()`
config.title = "Title of the UIButton"
config.image = UIImage(systemName: "line.horizontal.3.decrease.circle.fill",
                                   withConfiguration: UIImage.SymbolConfiguration(scale: .small)) // Change the scale here
config.imagePadding = 4 // Padding between image and title
            
let menuButton = UIButton()
menuButton.configuration = config
```

Comment: priceless answer, I had no idea it was changed that way. thanks, bountied!

Answer (score 6):

Objective C:

```
UIImageSymbolConfiguration * configuration = [UIImageSymbolConfiguration configurationWithPointSize:30 weight:UIImageSymbolWeightBold scale:UIImageSymbolScaleLarge];
UIImage * image = [UIImage systemImageNamed:@"" withConfiguration:configuration];
[_btn setImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Answer (score 2):

Just 3 steps for anyone using Xcode 15 and without diving into code:

1. Open your storyboard/XIB and click on the UIButton.
2. Hit up the Attributes inspector and look for the 'Default symbol Configuration’ section.
3. There's a 'Point Size' field — just punch in the number for how big you want your symbol.

Check out this GIF to see it in action:

[image]