# How do you make a UIButton with no text be the size of its image?

Tags: ios, uikit

I created a `UIButton` in Interface Builder that consists of only an SF Symbol and no text. The button draws with insets around the image, which affects how it's positioned with constraints. How do I remove that extra space, so that the button view is just the size of the SF Symbol image?

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change a SF Symbol size inside a UIButton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60641048/change-a-sf-symbol-size-inside-a-uibutton)

Comment: Unfortunately that has the same issue where the button doesn't take on the intrinsic size of the SF Symbol.

Answer (score 1):

#### Button with the intrinsic size of the Image

[image]

A button will take the size of the image by default. but since SF-Symbols are vectors, they can be scaled to any size. Each symbol has a few predefined sizes that you can choose:

[image: predefined Sizes]

Also, you can set your own size in the code:

```
let config = UIImage.SymbolConfiguration(pointSize: 160, weight: .bold, scale: .large)
       
let largeChevronImage = UIImage(systemName: "chevron.right.circle.fill", withConfiguration: config)

button.setImage(largeChevronImage, for: .normal)
```

---

#### Add or Remove Extra space around the image

Some images and SF-Symbols have some paddings around their content. You can control the size of the padding by setting the `ContentEdgeInsets`

[image: Offset]

<sub>You can clip the bounds to hide the out of frame content</sub>

<sub>All SF-Symbols have same size</sub>